# Math Drills and Times Tables in British English

Tags: british-english, mathematics

I'm working on an educational mobile app/game for kids to practice basic arithmetic skills like multiplication, addition, etc. I'm more familiar with the US market and now I struggle with proper and familiar terms for the British market (primary schools). Specifically:

1. Is "math drills" a proper british term describing practicing arithmetics like 5x3, 8-2, etc.? What are some alternatives?
2. What about "times tables" or "timestables" - it doesn't seem to be as popular in British usage than it is in American... Is there any better term a British parent would use to find an app for their children to practice multiplication?

Thank you for any insights. I apologize if I used wrong platform to ask these questions.

Comment: 'Multiplication tables' is acceptable and obviously higher register, but 'times tables' still seems the more common term for use with primary school children in the UK. [These Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=multiplication+tables%2Ctimes+tables&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) show at least that both terms are current, though they do not definitively indicate preferential usage in educational resources. // 'Maths drills' flatlines, though I encountered the usage when teaching maths.

Comment: Note that British English uses "[maths](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/maths)" not "math" as a short form of mathematics.

Comment: Traditionally the repetition of multiplication tables was practiced in British primary schools but the repetition of addition and subtraction combinations was not. There were plenty of exercises in other aspects of elementary arithmetic but not rote learning except of times tables and combinations of Imperial weights and measures and some combinations of currency before decimalisation. "Knowing your times tables" was an important skill to gain. The rote leaning did disappear from many schools for a while but it has returned but, so far as I know, only in the form of "times tables".

Comment: Thank you! So "maths exercises" would be a better term to describe an app that helps kids practice that simple arithmetics? It's not about memorizing; it's pure practice. I had an impression that "maths drills" have the same meaning. So "drills" suggest rote learning?

Comment: @BoldBen so "drills" implicates rote learning? "Math exercises" (or "maths exercises") is better term to cover both times tables and other arithmetic operations like addition, subtraction, etc. (which is not expected to be memorized)? Thank you!

Comment: In my time at primary school in England (late 1950s) we learned our "times tables" by chanting them. It was drummed into us that what we did with multiplication, division, addition and subtraction was arithmetic, not mathematics. We never had any form of rote learning for weights and measures, or currency. The word "drill" is not much used to describe such exercises, and tends to conjure up images of soldiers being put through their paces.

Answer (score 1):

Edwin Ashworth commented:

> 'Multiplication tables' is acceptable and obviously higher register, but 'times tables' still seems the more common term for use with primary school children in the UK. [These Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=multiplication+tables%2Ctimes+tables&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) show at least that both terms are current, though they do not definitively indicate preferential usage in educational resources. // 'Maths drills' flatlines, though I encountered the usage when teaching maths.